# TextView wont work in a custom method, but only in onCreate();

Tags: android

My textview is not behaving as I want it to.
When `newInstance` is called from my recyclerView adapter(when pressing on a item) it takes the user to a new Activity to show information about the pressed Item.

But when I use my textviews in the `newInstance` method, the demo-text "hello" is NOT shown and I get an `NullPointerException`, but in onCreate it works.

The error I get is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
com.example.muddii.traveldiary.TravelDiary.ShowNoteActivity.newInstance(ShowNoteActivity.java:54)
```

.

```
//Textview location works her and shows "helloooo" when it is in here
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_notepage);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Holiday at Red Sea");
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    location = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showLocation);
    location.setText("helloooo");


}


//Textview location dosn't work here
public static Intent newInstance(Context packageContext, long timestampID){


    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, ShowNoteActivity.class);
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(App.getAppContex());
    TravelNote getRowItem = realm.where(TravelNote.class).equalTo("timestamp", timestampID).findFirst();
    //getRowItem.getLocation().toString();


    location.setText("helloooo");
    return intent;
}
```

**newInstance is called my viewHolder in RecyclerView from here:**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(App.getAppContex(), "" + getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ShowNoteActivity showNoteActivity = new ShowNoteActivity();
        Intent intent = showNoteActivity.newInstance(App.getAppContex(),travelDiaries.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTimestamp());
        context.startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a non-static field from static reference.

Comment: I have tried to both making newInstance and TextView Location non-static, I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

static block are execute first and in static block you can use static fields only.

here location is not getting any reference and static block try to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

When is `newInstance()` being called and how does it know what your layout file is?

As it is a static method it has no knowledge of the rest of the fields in your class, mainly the `location` field.

I am assuming your class is being initialised via the `newInstance()` method, which will be called before your `onCreate` method, as a result, your layout will not yet have been inflated and set as the content view, therefore the location textfield does not exist yet.

Even using a static instance of `location` you will still get a null pointer because you will have one of the 2 following scenarios

1. You will not have loaded your layout file (i.e. setContentView)
2. You will have previously loaded your content view, and therefore your static variable will now point to the textview in the view that has been recycled.

Make sure that you are only accessing the location variable after you have called:

```
location = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showLocation);
```

Comment: My newInstance is called in the RecyclerView Viewholder's onClick method: I have updated the thread see it.

Comment: If you look at the process in which you are calling newInstance, you are calling it straight after creating the object. At this point, the onCreate method has not been called. Try putting the following into the top of the `newInstance` method ----- `onCreate(new Bundle());`